# Is memorization necessary in learning computer science?

Tags: learning-theory, theory

### Backgrounds

Hi guys, I am now trying to teach myself some basic computer science theories. Specifically, I am using the book, CSAPP (computer systems, from a programmer’s perspective) and 15-213 taught by CMU

### Question

My question is whether I need to memorize all the details covered in such theoretical courses (eg. the structure of an ELF file, the process of linking). If not, what is the methodology in approaching computer science theories.

This becomes even confusing when we have got searching engines now, considering we can always search for the facts that we need. If so, what is the purpose of learning? What shall we learn?

Comment: https://www.scientificamerican.com/article/internet-transactive-memory/

Comment: Perhaps relevant to [cseducators.se].

Comment: Yes, to learn you need to memorize. The existence of search engines won't save you from memorization, since you still need to remember the correspondence between topics and key words. Once you find the content, you still need to remember enough about it to be able to understand what is being said. Questioning the learning process won't save you from it. The time that you expended posting this question is time you didn't use to study. The more you aim to keep in your head the more it will stay. Don't aim for economy, aim for structured and interconnected information.

Answer (score 2):

It's hard to answer what you "need", as that depends on your purpose, and hard to answer this question concretely, as it is very broad.  I recommend you focus on learning concepts and ideas, as these are more likely to be of lasting use.  Sometimes, though, to understand how some interesting capability is achieved, you will need to understand the details of how it is implemented.  In general, if you pick a good textbook, then it's likely that there will be a lot of worthwhile material in there.  Saying much more might require getting into specifics.